# How do you get a file descriptor from a download url in python?

Tags: python-2.7

I would like to implement this. From a download link i want the file descriptor to the file the download URL contains.

Answer (score 1):

Did you perhaps want to obtain a file-handle like object to the file?

```
url = "http://www.acme.co/TNT.zip"
import urllib2
file_object = urllib2.urlopen(url)
```

Some file download sites require GET or POST form data to specify which file you want. `urllib2.urlopen()` takes optional arguments for passing in POST form data and setting a timeout in seconds.

If you need to pass GET data in the URL, try `urllib.urlencode()`.